# SVG Filters in Safari: x, y, width, height not being applied

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, svg-filters

Issue:

- In Safari, both filters show up - but both are the full width/height of the rectangle, so only the top one is visible.

How do I get this to work consistently across browsers?

Demo of bug here: https://codepen.io/mknepprath/pen/mKeObo.
Open in Chrome or Firefox to see how it should look. Thanks!

html:

```
<svg class='a'>
  <defs>
    <filter id='hey'>
      <feColorMatrix
        type='matrix'
        result='darken'
        values='.2 .05  .05 0 .35
                .05 .2  .05 0 .35
                .05 .05 .2  0 .35
                0   0    0  1 0'
      />
      <feColorMatrix
        in='SourceGraphic'
        result='node'
        x='5'
        y='5'
        width='90'
        height='90'
      />
      <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode in='darken' />
        <feMergeNode in='node' />
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
<div class='b' style='filter: url(#hey)'></div>
```

css:

```
.a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.b {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: peachpuff;
}
```

Chrome & Firefox:
[image: chrome preview]
Safari:
[image: safari bug preview]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many filter features don't work on Safari when you apply an SVG filter to HTML content using the CSS filter trapdoor. It looks like you found another case of this. If you want to keep doing this with filters, do this completely in SVG.

Comment: Thanks! This is that case - I've switched to applying it to an SVG now and it works great. 